# dont save a customer in stripe

Tags: javascript, php, forms, stripe-payments

/*Form*/

```
<form action="submit.php" id="payment-form" method="post">
<p>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Card Number" data-stripe="number">
</p>    
<p> 
<input type="text" placeholder="CVC" data-stripe="cvc">
</p> 
<p>
<input type="text" placeholder="expire-month" data-stripe="exp-month">
<input type="text" placeholder="expire-year" data-stripe="exp-year"> 
</p>
<!-- Buttons -->
<button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

/*script in the page html*/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"> </script>
<script>
Stripe.setPublishableKey('secret_key');

$('#payment-form').submit(function(e){
$form =$(this);
$form.find('button').prop('disbled', true);
Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response){
var token = response.id;
$form.append($('<input type="hidden name="stripe-token/>').val(token));
$form.get(0).submit();
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

/*PHP PAGE-submit.php*/

```
<?php
include_once 'vendor/stripe/stripe-php/Stripe.php';
//secret key
Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_key');
$token = $_POST['stripe-token'];
var_dump($token);
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create([
"card"  => $token,
"description"    => "paycar"
]);
?>
```

- i need to save a customer in stripe for using later for payments, form work, but php page doesnt show me the token and Stripe_customer::create ,doesnt work and when i put a var_dump but dont print anything ,

Comment: I'm not sure what `Stripe_Customer` is — shouldn't it be [`\Stripe\Customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php) instead?

Comment: Also, unless you have a really good reason, you should not be using stripe.js v2, as it puts you in a more burdensome [PCI compliance scope](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance). You should use [Elements and Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but aren't you missing two quotation marks in 
the following statement.

`$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripe-token"/>').val(token));`